# How to login without loss form data after session Logout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I work on ERP. Client fill the form data and due to some reason he work other work. If when client come back and again fill and submit form then session out and and form data be blank .
So client repeatedly fill all data again. How to avoid this.
**If session is expire then Form data not clean user login again and form is submit**

Answer (score 0):

redirect to login form and login with credential then submit the form.